# How to check overflow for multiplication of 16 bit integers in SSE?

Tags: c, vectorization, sse, simd, intrinsics

I want to implement a simple function in SSE (a program like [Izhikevich spiking neuron model](https://www.izhikevich.org/publications/spikes.pdf)). It should work with 16 bit signed integers (8.8 fixed point) and it needs to check the overflow condition during some integration step, and set a SSE mask (if overflow occured):

```
// initialized like following:
short I = 0x1BAD; // current injected to neuron
short vR = 0xF00D; // some reset threshold when spiked (negative)

// step to be vectorized:
short v0 = vReset;
for(;;) {

    // v0*v0/16 likely overflows => use 32 bit (16.16)
    short v0_sqr = ((int)v0)*((int)v0) / (1<<(8+4)); // not sure how "(v0*v0)>>(8+4)" would affect sign..
     // or   ((int)v0)*((int)v0) >> (8+4); // arithmetic right shift
     // original paper used v' = (v0^2)/25 + ...

    short v1 = v0_sqr + v0 + I;
    int m; // mask is set when neuron fires
    if(v1_overflows_during_this_operation()) { // "v1 > 0x7FFF" - way to detect?
        m=0xFFFFFFFF;
    else
        m=0;
    v0 = ( v1 & ~m ) | (vR & m );
}
```

But I haven't found the `_mm_mul_epi16()` instruction, to check high word of the multiplication. Why, and how such task `v1_overflows_during_this_operation()` is supposed to be implemented in SSE?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `short v1 = (v0*v0>>6) + v0 + I;`?  Assuming this is real C, `+` has higher precedence than `>>`, so you wrote `v1 = v0*v0 >> (6 + v0 + I)`.  NVM, you edited right as I was commenting.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I've fixed things up. In the original paper it was like `v' = (v0^2)/25 + ...`. Later on i though,t i can mix fixed point multiplication and that division into a 32bit operation.

Comment: SSE doesn't have 16x16=>32 bit multiply.  It has separate low/high half multiply instructions.  Hopefully we can do one multiply for overflow-check, and another for the real result.

Comment: You're only worried about the sign for your last edit, right?  (Because C doesn't guarantee arithmetic right shifts for negative integers).  You don't actually *need* signed-division rounding semantics (truncate towards 0) instead of arithmetic right shift (round towards -Inf), do you?

Comment: @PeterCordes So do you think it is easier not to allow result to overflow, and just to generate mask with _mm_cmpge_epi16(v1, vThreshold) as author does in the original paper?

Comment: Hell yes!  gaining another bit or two of precision would cost you maybe a factor of 2 in performance, because you'd have to compute another multiply result to check for overflow, or effectively widen to 32-bit (cutting the number of elements per vector in half).

Comment: @PeterCordes rounding semantics: i think floor() would be suffient enough..

Comment: Ok, then you should arithmetic right shift, instead of dividing by a power of 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes heh, so.. You mean that I could handle it like that: `short v0_tmp = v0 >> ((8+4)/2); short v0_sqr = v0_tmp * v0_tmp;` I would agree, because this term is only meaningful in terms of "magnitude" and normally, in AdEx model, is an exponential term: `v0_sqr=exp((v0-vt)/k)`

Comment: oh, you can lose that many low bits from `v0`?  Sure, do that, then.  Or you could maybe left-shift it and use `pmulhrsw` to get rounding of the high half of the multiply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181120/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike 32x32 => 64, there is no widening 16x16 -> 32 SSE multiplication instruction.

Instead, there's [`_mm_mulhi_epi16` and `_mm_mulhi_epu16`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,SVML,Other&expand=1276,5146,5146,3703&text=pmulh) which give you just the signed or unsigned upper half of the full result.

(and `_mm_mullo_epi16`, which does packed 16x16 => 16-bit low half truncating multiply, which is the same for signed or unsigned).

You could use `_mm_unpacklo/hi_epi16` to interleave low/high halves into a pair of vectors with 32-bit elements, but that would be pretty slow.  But yes, you could `_mm_srai_epi32(v, 8+4)` arithmetic right-shift that by 12 and then re-pack, maybe with `_mm_packs_epi32` (signed saturation back to 16-bit).  Then I guess check for saturation?

---

Your use case is unusual.  There's [`_mm_mulhrs_epi16`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,SVML,Other&expand=1276,5146,5146,3727&text=pmulh) which gives you the high 17 bits, rounded off and then truncated to 16 bits.  (See the description).  That's useful for some fixed-point algorithms where inputs are scaled to put the result in the upper half, and you want to round including the low half instead of truncate.

You might actually use `_mm_mulhrs_epi16` or `_mm_mulhi_epi16` as your best bet for keeping the most precision, maybe by left-shifting your `v0` before squaring to just the point where the high half will give you `(v0*v0) >> (8+4)`.

> So do you think it is easier not to allow result to overflow, and just to generate mask with `_mm_cmpge_epi16(v1, vThreshold)` as author does in the original paper?

Hell yes! gaining another bit or two of precision would cost you maybe a factor of 2 in performance, because you'd have to compute another multiply result to check for overflow, or effectively widen to 32-bit (cutting the number of elements per vector in half), as described above.

With a compare result, `v0 = ( v1 & ~m ) | (vR & m );` becomes an SSE4.1 blend: [`_mm_blendv_epi8`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,SVML,Other&expand=1276,5146,5146,432&text=blendv).

---

**If your `vThreshold` has 2 unset bits at the top, you have room to left shift without losing any of the most-significant bits**.  Since `mulhi` gives you `(v0*v0) >> 16`, so you can do this:

```
// losing the high 2 bits of v0
__m128i v0_lshift2   = _mm_slli_epi16(v0, 2);    // left by 2 before squaring
__m128i v0_sqr_asr12 = _mm_mulhi_epi16(v0_lshift2, v0_lshift2);
__m128i v1 = _mm_add_epi16(v0, I);
        v1 = _mm_add_epi16(v1, v0_sqr_asr12);

    // v1 = ((v0<<2)* (int)(v0<<2))) >> 16) + v0 + I

    // v1 = ((v0*(int)v0) >> 12) + v0 + I
```

Left shift by 2 before squaring is the same as left shift by 4 after squaring (of the full 32-bit result).  It puts the 16 bits we want into the high 16 exactly.

But this is unusable if your `v0` is so close to full range that you'd potentially overflow when left-shifting.

**Otherwise, you can lose 6 low bits of `v0` before multiplying**

Rounding towards -Infinity with an arithmetic right shift loses 6 bits of precision, but overflow is impossible.

```
// losing the low 6 bits of v0
__m128i v0_asr6 = _mm_srai_epi16(v0, 6);
__m128i v0_sqr_asr12 = _mm_mullo_epi16(v0_asr6, v0_asr6);
__m128i v1 = _mm_add_epi16(v0, I);
        v1 = _mm_add_epi16(v1, v0_sqr_asr12);

    // v1 =  (v0>>6) * (int)(v0>>6)) + v0 + I

    // v1 ~= ((v0*(int)v0) >> 12) + v0 + I
```

I think you're losing more precision this way, so it's probably better to set `vThreshold` small enough that you have enough overhead to use high-half multiplies.  This way includes maybe-worse rounding.

`pmulhrsw` to round instead of truncate might be even better, if we can set up for it as efficiently.  But I don't think we can because the right-shift by 1 is an odd number.  I think we'd need to make 2 separate inputs, one `v0_lshift2` and one only left shifted by 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Lower bits are of no matter, as all "neural stuff" is mainly about accumulating statistics. Only magnitude of this quadratic term matters, determining - *"would the cell now excitate or inhibit"* for given current `I` and `v0`

Comment: Thanks for blend! Could you advise me a good book, where i could read all about such common SSE practices?

Comment: @xakepp35: I recommend Agner Fog's x86 asm optimization manual (https://agner.org/optimize/).  His chapter on SIMD has a very nice table of useful data-movement instructions (shuffles/blends) for various purposes.  Also, if you leave out AVX512, there aren't *that* many SSE instructions.  I used to just look over the list of x86 asm instructions when I was hoping to find one that could be useful.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html.  (The asm instruction set manual lists intrinsics at the bottom, or use the intrinsics finder I linked.  It also has a breakdown by category).

Comment: @xakepp35: Did you try my short block of intrinsics code?  I'm pretty sure it does what you want, left shifting to feed a high-half multiply instead of right-shifting to feed a low-half multiply.  Those are exactly equivalent except for when the rounding happens.  My answer does already mention `_mm_mullo_epi16`, but I recommend against using that.  Binary fixed-point Just Works as long as you get your shift counts right; it doesn't matter if some of your intermediate results don't have the point in the same position.

Comment: Seems that system would break exactly if `v0=0x4000`: What would be the value of `v0_sqr_asr12`? On the other hand `((v0>>4)^^2)>>4` (with use of lower 16 bits for squaring) would also break..

Comment: @xakepp35: Yeah, my first version of this is only safe if `vThreshold` is small enough that `v0` always has room to left-shift by 2 without losing any significant bits.  Updated my answer with a version that works for smaller `vThreshold`, but it loses 6 bits of v0 before the lo multiply.

Comment: I think your first solution with `v0<<2` is better, just have to check for mask `m=cmpgt_epi16(v1, 0x1FFF)` after step to determine "If this gonna fire(overflow) on the next iteration?" - and reset it with to `vReset` with blend

Comment: @xakepp35: Yeah, if you can choose `vThreshold` to prevent overflow in the next iteration, the first way is definitely better because it keeps more precision.  BTW, if `vReset = -1`, you can `v0 = v1 | compare_result`.  (`x | 0 = x`,  `x | -1 = -1`, for all x).  For any other vReset you'll have to blend, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181119/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-peter-cordes).